# I am getting Procedure too large issue in VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,  I am getting Procedure too large issue in VBA macro while  I am trying to execute the following macro.  How can I minimise the following codes?.  Please help

```
Sub detailedsalarydue()

    Dim Lastrow1 As Long
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Set Sh1 = Sheets("detailedsalary")
    Lastrow1 = Sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sh1.Range("A" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("B8").Value
    Sh1.Range("B" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D8").Value
    Sh1.Range("C" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c12").Value
    Sh1.Range("D" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c13").Value
    Sh1.Range("E" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c14").Value
    Sh1.Range("F" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c15").Value
    Sh1.Range("G" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c16").Value
    Sh1.Range("H" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c17").Value
    Sh1.Range("I" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c18").Value
    Sh1.Range("J" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c19").Value
    Sh1.Range("K" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c20").Value
    Sh1.Range("L" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c21").Value
    Sh1.Range("M" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c22").Value
    Sh1.Range("N" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c23").Value
    Sh1.Range("O" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c24").Value
    Sh1.Range("P" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c25").Value
    Sh1.Range("Q" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c26").Value
    Sh1.Range("R" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c27").Value
    Sh1.Range("S" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c28").Value
    Sh1.Range("T" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c29").Value
    Sh1.Range("U" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c30").Value
    Sh1.Range("V" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c31").Value
    Sh1.Range("W" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c32").Value
    Sh1.Range("X" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c33").Value
    Sh1.Range("Y" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c34").Value
    Sh1.Range("Z" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c35").Value
    Sh1.Range("AA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("C36").Value
    Sh1.Range("AB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("C37").Value
    Sh1.Range("AC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c38").Value
    Sh1.Range("AD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c39").Value
    Sh1.Range("AE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c40").Value
    Sh1.Range("AF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c41").Value
    Sh1.Range("AG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c42").Value
    Sh1.Range("AH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c43").Value
    Sh1.Range("AI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c44").Value
    Sh1.Range("AJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c45").Value
    Sh1.Range("AK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c46").Value
    Sh1.Range("AL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c47").Value
    Sh1.Range("AM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c48").Value
    Sh1.Range("AN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("c49").Value
    Sh1.Range("AO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D12").Value
    Sh1.Range("AP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D13").Value
    Sh1.Range("AQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D14").Value
    Sh1.Range("AR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D15").Value
    Sh1.Range("AS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D16").Value
    Sh1.Range("AT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D17").Value
    Sh1.Range("AU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D18").Value
    Sh1.Range("AV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D19").Value
    Sh1.Range("AW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D20").Value
    Sh1.Range("AX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D21").Value
    Sh1.Range("AY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D22").Value
    Sh1.Range("AZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D23").Value
    Sh1.Range("BA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D24").Value
    Sh1.Range("BB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D25").Value
    Sh1.Range("BC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D26").Value
    Sh1.Range("BD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D27").Value
    Sh1.Range("BE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D28").Value
    Sh1.Range("BF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D29").Value
    Sh1.Range("BG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D30").Value
    Sh1.Range("BH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D31").Value
    Sh1.Range("BI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D32").Value
    Sh1.Range("BJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D33").Value
    Sh1.Range("BK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D34").Value
    Sh1.Range("BL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D35").Value
    Sh1.Range("BM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D36").Value
    Sh1.Range("BN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D37").Value
    Sh1.Range("BO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D38").Value
    Sh1.Range("BP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D39").Value
    Sh1.Range("BQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D40").Value
    Sh1.Range("BR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D41").Value
    Sh1.Range("BS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D42").Value
    Sh1.Range("BT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D43").Value
    Sh1.Range("BU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D44").Value
    Sh1.Range("BV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D45").Value
    Sh1.Range("BW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D46").Value
    Sh1.Range("BX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D47").Value
    Sh1.Range("BY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D48").Value
    Sh1.Range("BZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D49").Value
    Sh1.Range("CA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E12").Value
    Sh1.Range("CB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E13").Value
    Sh1.Range("CC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E14").Value
    Sh1.Range("CD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E15").Value
    Sh1.Range("CE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E16").Value
    Sh1.Range("CF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E17").Value
    Sh1.Range("CG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E18").Value
    Sh1.Range("CH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E19").Value
    Sh1.Range("CI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E20").Value
    Sh1.Range("CJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E21").Value
    Sh1.Range("CK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E22").Value
    Sh1.Range("CL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E23").Value
    Sh1.Range("CM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E24").Value
    Sh1.Range("CN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E25").Value
    Sh1.Range("CO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E26").Value
    Sh1.Range("CP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E27").Value
    Sh1.Range("CQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E28").Value
    Sh1.Range("CR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E29").Value
    Sh1.Range("CS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E30").Value
    Sh1.Range("CT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E31").Value
    Sh1.Range("CU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E32").Value
    Sh1.Range("CV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E33").Value
    Sh1.Range("CW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E34").Value
    Sh1.Range("CX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E35").Value
    Sh1.Range("CY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E36").Value
    Sh1.Range("CZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E37").Value
    Sh1.Range("DA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E38").Value
    Sh1.Range("DB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E39").Value
    Sh1.Range("DC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E40").Value
    Sh1.Range("DD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E41").Value
    Sh1.Range("DE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E42").Value
    Sh1.Range("DF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E43").Value
    Sh1.Range("DG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E44").Value
    Sh1.Range("DH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E45").Value
    Sh1.Range("DI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E46").Value
    Sh1.Range("DJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E47").Value
    Sh1.Range("DK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E48").Value
    Sh1.Range("DL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("E49").Value
    Sh1.Range("DM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G12").Value
    Sh1.Range("DN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G13").Value
    Sh1.Range("DO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G14").Value
    Sh1.Range("DP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G15").Value
    Sh1.Range("DQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G16").Value
    Sh1.Range("DR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G17").Value
    Sh1.Range("DS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G18").Value
    Sh1.Range("DT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G19").Value
    Sh1.Range("DU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G20").Value
    Sh1.Range("DV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G21").Value
    Sh1.Range("DW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G22").Value
    Sh1.Range("DX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G23").Value
    Sh1.Range("DY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G24").Value
    Sh1.Range("DZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G25").Value
    Sh1.Range("EA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G26").Value
    Sh1.Range("EB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G27").Value
    Sh1.Range("EC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G28").Value
    Sh1.Range("ED" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G29").Value
    Sh1.Range("EE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G30").Value
    Sh1.Range("EF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G31").Value
    Sh1.Range("EG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G32").Value
    Sh1.Range("EH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G33").Value
    Sh1.Range("EI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G34").Value
    Sh1.Range("EJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G35").Value
    Sh1.Range("EK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G36").Value
    Sh1.Range("EL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G37").Value
    Sh1.Range("EM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G38").Value
    Sh1.Range("EN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G39").Value
    Sh1.Range("EO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G40").Value
    Sh1.Range("EP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G41").Value
    Sh1.Range("EQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G42").Value
    Sh1.Range("ER" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G43").Value
    Sh1.Range("ES" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G44").Value
    Sh1.Range("ET" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G45").Value
    Sh1.Range("EU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G46").Value
    Sh1.Range("EV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G47").Value
    Sh1.Range("EW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G48").Value
    Sh1.Range("EX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("G49").Value
    Sh1.Range("EY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H12").Value
    Sh1.Range("EZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H13").Value
    Sh1.Range("FA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H14").Value
    Sh1.Range("FB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H15").Value
    Sh1.Range("FC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H16").Value
    Sh1.Range("FD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H17").Value
    Sh1.Range("FE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H18").Value
    Sh1.Range("FF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H19").Value
    Sh1.Range("FG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H20").Value
    Sh1.Range("FH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H21").Value
    Sh1.Range("FI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H22").Value
    Sh1.Range("FJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H23").Value
    Sh1.Range("FK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H24").Value
    Sh1.Range("FL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H25").Value
    Sh1.Range("FM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H26").Value
    Sh1.Range("FN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H27").Value
    Sh1.Range("FO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H28").Value
    Sh1.Range("FP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H29").Value
    Sh1.Range("FQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H30").Value
    Sh1.Range("FR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H31").Value
    Sh1.Range("FS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H32").Value
    Sh1.Range("FT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H33").Value
    Sh1.Range("FU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H34").Value
    Sh1.Range("FV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H35").Value
    Sh1.Range("FW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H36").Value
    Sh1.Range("FX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H37").Value
    Sh1.Range("FY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H38").Value
    Sh1.Range("FZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H39").Value
    Sh1.Range("GA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H40").Value
    Sh1.Range("GB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H41").Value
    Sh1.Range("GC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H42").Value
    Sh1.Range("GD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H43").Value
    Sh1.Range("GE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H44").Value
    Sh1.Range("GF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H45").Value
    Sh1.Range("GG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H46").Value
    Sh1.Range("GH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H47").Value
    Sh1.Range("GI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H48").Value
    Sh1.Range("GJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("H49").Value
    Sh1.Range("GK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I12").Value
    Sh1.Range("GL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I13").Value
    Sh1.Range("GM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I14").Value
    Sh1.Range("GN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I15").Value
    Sh1.Range("GO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I16").Value
    Sh1.Range("GP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I17").Value
    Sh1.Range("GQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I18").Value
    Sh1.Range("GR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I19").Value
    Sh1.Range("GS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I20").Value
    Sh1.Range("GT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I21").Value
    Sh1.Range("GU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I22").Value
    Sh1.Range("GV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I23").Value
    Sh1.Range("GW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I24").Value
    Sh1.Range("GX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I25").Value
    Sh1.Range("GY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I26").Value
    Sh1.Range("GZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I27").Value
    Sh1.Range("HA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I28").Value
    Sh1.Range("HB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I29").Value
    Sh1.Range("HC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I30").Value
    Sh1.Range("HD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I31").Value
    Sh1.Range("HE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I32").Value
    Sh1.Range("HF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I33").Value
    Sh1.Range("HG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I34").Value
    Sh1.Range("HH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I35").Value
    Sh1.Range("HI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I36").Value
    Sh1.Range("HJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I37").Value
    Sh1.Range("HK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I38").Value
    Sh1.Range("HL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I39").Value
    Sh1.Range("HM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I40").Value
    Sh1.Range("HN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I41").Value
    Sh1.Range("HO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I42").Value
    Sh1.Range("HP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I43").Value
    Sh1.Range("HQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I44").Value
    Sh1.Range("HR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I45").Value
    Sh1.Range("HS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I46").Value
    Sh1.Range("HT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I47").Value
    Sh1.Range("HU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I48").Value
    Sh1.Range("HV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("I49").Value
    Sh1.Range("HW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J12").Value
    Sh1.Range("HX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J13").Value
    Sh1.Range("HY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J14").Value
    Sh1.Range("HZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J15").Value
    Sh1.Range("IA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J16").Value
    Sh1.Range("IB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J17").Value
    Sh1.Range("IC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J18").Value
    Sh1.Range("ID" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J19").Value
    Sh1.Range("IE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J20").Value
    Sh1.Range("IF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J21").Value
    Sh1.Range("IG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J22").Value
    Sh1.Range("IH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J23").Value
    Sh1.Range("II" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J24").Value
    Sh1.Range("IJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J25").Value
    Sh1.Range("IK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J26").Value
    Sh1.Range("IL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J27").Value
    Sh1.Range("IM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J28").Value
    Sh1.Range("IN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J29").Value
    Sh1.Range("IO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J30").Value
    Sh1.Range("IP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J31").Value
    Sh1.Range("IQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J32").Value
    Sh1.Range("IR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J33").Value
    Sh1.Range("IS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J34").Value
    Sh1.Range("IT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J35").Value
    Sh1.Range("IU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J36").Value
    Sh1.Range("IV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J37").Value
    Sh1.Range("IW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J38").Value
    Sh1.Range("IX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J39").Value
    Sh1.Range("IY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J40").Value
    Sh1.Range("IZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J41").Value
    Sh1.Range("JA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J42").Value
    Sh1.Range("JB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J43").Value
    Sh1.Range("JC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J44").Value
    Sh1.Range("JD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J45").Value
    Sh1.Range("JE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J46").Value
    Sh1.Range("JF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J47").Value
    Sh1.Range("JG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J48").Value
    Sh1.Range("JH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("J49").Value
    Sh1.Range("JI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K12").Value
    Sh1.Range("JJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K13").Value
    Sh1.Range("JK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K14").Value
    Sh1.Range("JL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K15").Value
    Sh1.Range("JM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K16").Value
    Sh1.Range("JN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K17").Value
    Sh1.Range("JO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K18").Value
    Sh1.Range("JP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K19").Value
    Sh1.Range("JQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K20").Value
    Sh1.Range("JR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K21").Value
    Sh1.Range("JS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K22").Value
    Sh1.Range("JT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K23").Value
    Sh1.Range("JU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K24").Value
    Sh1.Range("JV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K25").Value
    Sh1.Range("JW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K26").Value
    Sh1.Range("JX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K27").Value
    Sh1.Range("JY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K28").Value
    Sh1.Range("JZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K29").Value
    Sh1.Range("KA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K30").Value
    Sh1.Range("KB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K31").Value
    Sh1.Range("KC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K32").Value
    Sh1.Range("KD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K33").Value
    Sh1.Range("KE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K34").Value
    Sh1.Range("KF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K35").Value
    Sh1.Range("KG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K36").Value
    Sh1.Range("KH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K37").Value
    Sh1.Range("KI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K38").Value
    Sh1.Range("KJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K39").Value
    Sh1.Range("KK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K40").Value
    Sh1.Range("KL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K41").Value
    Sh1.Range("KM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K42").Value
    Sh1.Range("KN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K43").Value
    Sh1.Range("KO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K44").Value
    Sh1.Range("KP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K45").Value
    Sh1.Range("KQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K46").Value
    Sh1.Range("KR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K47").Value
    Sh1.Range("KS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K48").Value
    Sh1.Range("KT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("K49").Value
    Sh1.Range("KU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L12").Value
    Sh1.Range("KV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L13").Value
    Sh1.Range("KW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L14").Value
    Sh1.Range("KX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L15").Value
    Sh1.Range("KY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L16").Value
    Sh1.Range("KZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L17").Value
    Sh1.Range("LA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L18").Value
    Sh1.Range("LB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L19").Value
    Sh1.Range("LC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L20").Value
    Sh1.Range("LD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L21").Value
    Sh1.Range("LE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L22").Value
    Sh1.Range("LF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L23").Value
    Sh1.Range("LG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L24").Value
    Sh1.Range("LH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L25").Value
    Sh1.Range("LI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L26").Value
    Sh1.Range("LJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L27").Value
    Sh1.Range("LK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L28").Value
    Sh1.Range("LL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L29").Value
    Sh1.Range("LM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L30").Value
    Sh1.Range("LN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L31").Value
    Sh1.Range("LO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L32").Value
    Sh1.Range("LP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L33").Value
    Sh1.Range("LQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L34").Value
    Sh1.Range("LR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L35").Value
    Sh1.Range("LS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L36").Value
    Sh1.Range("LT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L37").Value
    Sh1.Range("LU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L38").Value
    Sh1.Range("LV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L39").Value
    Sh1.Range("LW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L40").Value
    Sh1.Range("LX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L41").Value
    Sh1.Range("LY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L42").Value
    Sh1.Range("LZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L43").Value
    Sh1.Range("MA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L44").Value
    Sh1.Range("MB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L45").Value
    Sh1.Range("MC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L46").Value
    Sh1.Range("MD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L47").Value
    Sh1.Range("ME" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L48").Value
    Sh1.Range("MF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("L49").Value
    Sh1.Range("MG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M12").Value
    Sh1.Range("MH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M13").Value
    Sh1.Range("MI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M14").Value
    Sh1.Range("MJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M15").Value
    Sh1.Range("MK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M16").Value
    Sh1.Range("ML" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M17").Value
    Sh1.Range("MM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M18").Value
    Sh1.Range("MN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M19").Value
    Sh1.Range("MO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M20").Value
    Sh1.Range("MP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M21").Value
    Sh1.Range("MQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M22").Value
    Sh1.Range("MR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M23").Value
    Sh1.Range("MS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M24").Value
    Sh1.Range("MT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M25").Value
    Sh1.Range("MU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M26").Value
    Sh1.Range("MV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M27").Value
    Sh1.Range("MW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M28").Value
    Sh1.Range("MX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M29").Value
    Sh1.Range("MY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M30").Value
    Sh1.Range("MZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M31").Value
    Sh1.Range("NA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M32").Value
    Sh1.Range("NB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M33").Value
    Sh1.Range("NC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M34").Value
    Sh1.Range("ND" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M35").Value
    Sh1.Range("NE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M36").Value
    Sh1.Range("NF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M37").Value
    Sh1.Range("NG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M38").Value
    Sh1.Range("NH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M39").Value
    Sh1.Range("NI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M40").Value
    Sh1.Range("NJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M41").Value
    Sh1.Range("NK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M42").Value
    Sh1.Range("NL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M43").Value
    Sh1.Range("NM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M44").Value
    Sh1.Range("NN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M45").Value
    Sh1.Range("NO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M46").Value
    Sh1.Range("NP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M47").Value
    Sh1.Range("NQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M48").Value
    Sh1.Range("NR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("M49").Value
    Sh1.Range("NS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N12").Value
    Sh1.Range("NT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N13").Value
    Sh1.Range("NU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N14").Value
    Sh1.Range("NV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N15").Value
    Sh1.Range("NW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N16").Value
    Sh1.Range("NX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N17").Value
    Sh1.Range("NY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N18").Value
    Sh1.Range("NZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N19").Value
    Sh1.Range("OA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N20").Value
    Sh1.Range("OB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N21").Value
    Sh1.Range("OC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N22").Value
    Sh1.Range("OD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N23").Value
    Sh1.Range("OE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N24").Value
    Sh1.Range("OF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N25").Value
    Sh1.Range("OG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N26").Value
    Sh1.Range("OH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N27").Value
    Sh1.Range("OI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N28").Value
    Sh1.Range("OJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N29").Value
    Sh1.Range("OK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N30").Value
    Sh1.Range("OL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N31").Value
    Sh1.Range("OM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N32").Value
    Sh1.Range("ON" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N33").Value
    Sh1.Range("OO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N34").Value
    Sh1.Range("OP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N35").Value
    Sh1.Range("OQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N36").Value
    Sh1.Range("OR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N37").Value
    Sh1.Range("OS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N38").Value
    Sh1.Range("OT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N39").Value
    Sh1.Range("OU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N40").Value
    Sh1.Range("OV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N41").Value
    Sh1.Range("OW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N42").Value
    Sh1.Range("OX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N43").Value
    Sh1.Range("OY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N44").Value
    Sh1.Range("OZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N45").Value
    Sh1.Range("PA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N46").Value
    Sh1.Range("PB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N47").Value
    Sh1.Range("PC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N48").Value
    Sh1.Range("PD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("N49").Value
    Sh1.Range("PE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O12").Value
    Sh1.Range("PF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O13").Value
    Sh1.Range("PG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O14").Value
    Sh1.Range("PH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O15").Value
    Sh1.Range("PI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O16").Value
    Sh1.Range("PJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O17").Value
    Sh1.Range("PK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O18").Value
    Sh1.Range("PL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O19").Value
    Sh1.Range("PM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O20").Value
    Sh1.Range("PN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O21").Value
    Sh1.Range("PO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O22").Value
    Sh1.Range("PP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O23").Value
    Sh1.Range("PQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O24").Value
    Sh1.Range("PR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O25").Value
    Sh1.Range("PS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O26").Value
    Sh1.Range("PT" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O27").Value
    Sh1.Range("PU" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O28").Value
    Sh1.Range("PV" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O29").Value
    Sh1.Range("PW" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O30").Value
    Sh1.Range("PX" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O31").Value
    Sh1.Range("PY" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O32").Value
    Sh1.Range("PZ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O33").Value
    Sh1.Range("QA" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O34").Value
    Sh1.Range("QB" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O35").Value
    Sh1.Range("QC" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O36").Value
    Sh1.Range("QD" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O37").Value
    Sh1.Range("QE" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O38").Value
    Sh1.Range("QF" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O39").Value
    Sh1.Range("QG" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O40").Value
    Sh1.Range("QH" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O41").Value
    Sh1.Range("QI" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O42").Value

    Sh1.Range("QJ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O43").Value
    Sh1.Range("QK" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O44").Value
    Sh1.Range("QL" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O45").Value

    Sh1.Range("QM" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O46").Value
    Sh1.Range("QN" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O47").Value
    Sh1.Range("QO" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O48").Value
    Sh1.Range("QP" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O49").Value
    Sh1.Range("QQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O68").Value
    Sh1.Range("QR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O75").Value
    Sh1.Range("QS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O77").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to SO.. You can use transpose ?

Comment: You can perform these actions in one or more loops.

Comment: Or you can split it into several procedures, so that no single one is too large.

Comment: Or you can restructure your sheets so the assignments show some commonality (it looks like a mess of cells and columns now). Then you can write them in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ... it will make your code shorter

```
Sub detailedsalarydue()

    Dim Lastrow1 As Long
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim firstCl As Range, col As Range, i As Long
    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("detailedsalary")
    Lastrow1 = Sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Sh1.Range("A" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("B8").Value
    Sh1.Range("B" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("D8").Value
    
    'Transpose colums from C to O
    i = 49 - 12 + 1
    Set firstCl = Sh1.Range("C" & Lastrow1)
    For Each col In Sh1.Range("C12:E49,G12:O49").Columns
        firstCl.Resize(1, i).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(col.Value, 0, 1))
        Set firstCl = firstCl.Offset(, i)
    Next
        
    Sh1.Range("QQ" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O68").Value
    Sh1.Range("QR" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O75").Value
    Sh1.Range("QS" & Lastrow1).Value = Range("O77").Value

End Sub
```